# Consuming a service using WS in Play

Tags: scala, future, playframework-2.3

I was hoping someone can briefly go over the various ways of consuming a service (this one just returns a string, normally it would be JSON but I just want to understand the concepts here).

My service:

```
def ping = Action {
  Ok("pong")
}
```

Now in my Play (2.3.x) application, I want to call my client and display the response.

When working with Futures, I want to display the value.
I am a bit confused, what are all the ways I could call this method i.e. there are some ways I see that use Success/Failure,

```
val futureResponse: Future[String] = WS.url(url + "/ping").get().map { response =>
          response.body
 }
var resp = ""
futureResponse.onComplete {
  case Success(str) => {
    Logger.trace(s"future success $str")
    resp = str
  }
  case Failure(ex) => {
    Logger.trace(s"future failed")
    resp = ex.toString
  }
}

Ok(resp)
```

I can see the trace in STDOUT for success/failure, but my controller action just returns "" to my browser.

I understand that this is because it returns a FUTURE and my action finishes before the future returns.

How can I force it to wait?
What options do I have with error handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to block until feature is completed look at the `Future.ready()` and `Future.result()` methods. But you shouldn't.

The point about `Future` is that you can tell it how to use the result once it arrived, and then go on, no blocks required.

`Future` can be the result of an `Action`, in this case framework takes care of it:

```
def index = Action.async {
  WS.url(url + "/ping").get()
    .map(response => Ok("Got result: " + response.body))
}
```

Look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync), it describes the topic very well.

As for the error-handling, you can use `Future.recover()` method. You should tell it what to return in case of error and it gives you new `Future` that you should return from your action.

```
def index = Action.async {
  WS.url(url + "/ping").get()
    .map(response => Ok("Got result: " + response.body))
    .recover{ case e: Exception => InternalServerError(e.getMessage) }
}
```

So the basic way you consume service is to get result `Future`, transform it in the way you want by using monadic methods(the methods that return new transformed `Future`, like `map`, `recover`, etc..) and return it as a result of an `Action`.

You may want to look at [Play 2.2 -Scala - How to chain Futures in Controller Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547396/play-2-2-scala-how-to-chain-futures-in-controller-action?rq=1) and [Dealing with failed futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499336/dealing-with-failed-futures) questions.